# Does Google Analytics have a query language?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm working on a back-end script that takes some data from my Google Analytics account and sends it to another application. The script is controlled by a web client. I don't want to add too many UI elements in the web client (I don't want to build another Google Analytics Query Explorer like the one at https://ga-dev-tools.google/query-explorer/ ). I just want to offer 1 textbox and the user should write their query there.

On the back-end, I can query Google Analytics using their own libraries, which take in various parameters such as start date, end date, metrics, etc.. But each of these require some separate coding & validation client-side. Would be nice if there would be some sort of syntax for querying analytics data.

Comment: Are you building it for GA UA? UA is being deprecated soon. You probably want to build it for GA4. And you probably don't want to query GA's reporting API from your backend. Not when there's a very simple BigQuery connection and then you're suddenly using SQL querying BQ with the luxury of multiple well-maintained libraries.

Comment: @BNazaruk currently I can only work against GA UA. As for BigQuery, from what I read, it costs to use it. Anyway, it's ok, I got a very comprehensive answer from chatGPT, and without -1 votes to my question (don't care who -1 voted my question, and I'm aware that a lot of chatGPT's knowledge is or will be based on the knowledge gathered here, but damn this site sometimes gets my stomach in knots due to the stress of my questions falling underneath the Holy standards of who-knows...)

Comment: well, yeah, chatGPT can be useful, but it's often wrong. And it doesn't indicate the level of confidence. But if it works for you, then great.